# Flutter: FutureBuilder no list shown

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a list that comes in the form of future

```
  Future<List<String>> _future;
  List<String> showList = [];
  String showCode;

  Future<List<String>> getCode() async {
    final show = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      showList = show.getStringList('companyName');
    });
    print('here ${showList.toString()}');
    return showList;
  }
```

and when I print, my console will output like this

> [Friends,Scrubs]

I'm trying to show this list to user by using  Futurebuilder but my value is not show. I added it as a column in the container to be centered on the bottom.but only the CircularProgressIndicator() part is visible Any idea?

```
  ? Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context, ShowScreen.routeName);
                                }),
                            Text(
                              'Please Select Show',
                            
                          ],
                        ),
                        FutureBuilder(
                        future: _future,
                        builder: (context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Card(
                                      elevation: 6.0,
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ));
                                });
                          }  else{
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }

                        }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

looks like this, but its not show items

[image]

I set my data like this

```
else{

        _showData = !_showData;
       shows.forEach((element) {
               showCode = element.showName;
               showList.add(element.showName);
                show.setStringList(
              'showName', showList);
                getCode();
                                           
                                            })
```

Comment: Is this `ListView` nested in a `Column` ?

Comment: I edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Set `shrinkWrap` property of the `ListView` to `true`:

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```dart
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      shrinkWrap: true, // new line
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            elevation: 6.0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                ],
              ),
            ));
      },
    );
```

Comment: I added but there was no change

Comment: Check the console for any warnings or errors. It worked when I tried the fix I posted.

Comment: Does the `progress indicator` show ? Does it stop ? What happens immediately after it stops ?

Comment: keeps spinning, does not stop. I added a visual above to understand better

Comment: Can i see the `future` you are passing to the `FutureBuilder` widget ?

Comment: Where are you calling the `getCode` method ? You should have something like `_future = getCode()` in your `initState`.

Comment: yes when I add it to initState the loading screen disappears and there is a blank space (again no error)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221151/discussion-between-void-and-kimsoo).